# Connecting webserver container to a MySQL container

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I am learning docker and I created a MySQL container with a persistent database using volumes and I want to connect to the MySQL container from the web container during the `docker-compose up --build` procedure.

The problem is that the connection always fail during that time. I can only access the MySQL container after everything is finished.

The line `RUN mysql -uroot -pmy-root-password -hdatabase` in the `build/web-server/docker-compose.yml`file below, always fail.

How can I accomplish this?

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
    database:
        container_name: kadu-database
        build:
            context: build/database
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
    web-server:
        container_name: kadu-web-server
        links:
            - database
        depends_on:
            - database
        build:
            context: build/web-server
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

**build/database/docker-compose.yml**

```
FROM mariadb:5.5
ARG MYSQL_DATABASE
ARG MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install patch --assume-yes
```

**build/web-server/docker-compose.yml**

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
ARG WEB_USERNAME
ARG MYSQL_DATABASE
ARG MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
RUN apt-get update --quiet=2 && apt-get install mariadb-client --quiet=2 
RUN mysql -uroot -pmy-root-password -hdatabase
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by connecting to the database at the build phase?

Answer (score 1):

Working with docker includes 2 steps:

- building a image
- creating container based on image and running this container

The point is you `mysql client` can connect to server **only** on second step.

`Dockerfile` "executes" while you build image. In this time you don't have any containers, therefore you can't connect to them. 
You need move command  `RUN mysql -uroot -pmy-root-password -hdatabase` 
 from `Dockerfile` to [entrypoint.sh](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint)